# Is the composition of CDFs also a CDF?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Two functions $F(x)$ and $G(x)$ are known as cdf functions. Is
>   $$F(G (x))$$
>   necessarily a cdf function?

My answer is no, and here is my counterexample:

Because a cdf function qualifies:
  a. $0≤F(x)≤1$;
  b. $F(x)$ are non-decreasing;
  c. $F(x)$ are continuous from left to the right;
  d. $\lim_{x→−∞}F(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x→∞}F(x)=1$

and if 
$G(t) = 0$ when $t<1$

$G(t) = t^3$ when $0≤t≤1$

$G(t) = 1$ when $t>1$

and

$F(x) = 0$ when $x<2$

$F(x) = x^3$ when $2≤x≤3$

$F(x) = 1$ when $x>3$

then $F(G (t))$ will always equal $0$, which is against principle d, that $\lim_{x→∞}F(x)=1$. So $F(G (t))$ is not necessarily a cdf.

Does this counterexample look good? Can anyone give another counterexample maybe?

Comment: your counterexample is strange because $F(2)=8$. Also your statement about cdf's part (c) should be $F(x)$ is left continuous (i'm not sure what "from the left to the right" means).

Comment: Are you only considering cases where $[0,1]$ is the support of $G$? Otherwise, these functions can't be composed (lose their composure?).

Comment: $F$ isn't a CDF since $F(2)>1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, your $F$ is not a cdf because $x^3>1$ for $x\in[2,3]$. It works if you use $$F(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }x<2\\ (x-2)^3&\text{if }2\le x\le 3\\1&\text{if }x>3\end{cases}$$

*Other counterexamples:*

Properties $(a),\ (b)$ and $(d)$ basically imply that the composition $F\circ G$ of two cumulative distribution functions is almost never a cumulative distribution function: when it is, necessarily $\forall x\ge 1,\ F(x)=1$ and $\forall x\le 0,\ F(x)=0$.

So, if $F$ is the cdf of a probability which is not concentrated on $[0,1]$ (and there are lots of them), it makes a good counter-example whatever the $G$ you choose.

Comment: I think you mean $(x-2)^3$.

Comment: Damn those shifts... Thanks @DavidKleiman

Comment: @DavidKleiman why? It's not identically $1$ for $x\ge 1$, therefore $F\circ G$ cannot be a cdf for any cdf $G$. I fear I'm missing something.

Comment: Sorry I was confused. I thought we were doing $G(F(x))$, but of course $F(G(x))$ is not a CDF. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

Your counterexample is almost a good one -- you meant that 
$ G(x) = 0 $ when $x<0$, but you wrote $x<1$.